Azure Function v2 environment variables
When running the Azure Function locally, I would like the environment to be set to 'local' instead of Development. How would I make that change?

Microsoft info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings


When you create an Azure Function project, there is a JSON file called local.settings.json that comes with the template. The JSON file has a property called Values. Anything you add to it, will become an environment variable, so you can set AZURE_FUNCTIONS_ENVIRONMENT to "local" there.
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
        "AZURE_FUNCTIONS_ENVIRONMENT": "local"
    }
}


this does not work. It still reads from development.appsettings.json and env is set to development

You didn't mention that you had a Development.appsettings.json file. The default Azure Functions template uses local.settings.json. However, like in any .NET Core app, you can add additional JSON config files. It's hard to tell without seeing your configuration code, but I think in this case, you have to set AZURE_FUNCTIONS_ENVIRONMENT in the Development.appsetting.json file.

but development.appsettings.json is used for our DEV environment (deployed on Azure), Local is what we use for Local development

Can you show the code where you register those JSON config files? Also, do you have launchSettings.json file? If so, the environment variables can be set in launchSettings.sjon file too, so I'd check that.
